# Rspec for enum columns of type enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums

I have table crops, with an `enum` field `crop_type`. The type of the field is an enum field in PostGRES. The migration is as follows:

```
  def up
    create_table :crops do |t|
      t.string :name
      execute <<-SQL
      CREATE TYPE crop_type AS ENUM ('fruit', 'vegetable', 'other_crop');
      SQL
      t.column :crop_type, :crop_type
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

And the relevant model is as such:

```
class Crop < ApplicationRecord
  enum crop_type: { fruit: 'fruit', vegetable: 'vegetable', other_crop: 'other_crop' }
end
```

Now, in my model spec, I have the following line:

```
  it {
    should define_enum_for(:crop_type).with_values({ fruit: 'fruit', vegetable: 'vegetable', other_crop: 'other_crop' })
  }
```

Running this test however gives the error:

```
Expected Crop to define :crop_type as an enum backed by an integer,
       mapping ‹"fruit"› to ‹"fruit"›, ‹"vegetable"› to ‹"vegetable"›, and
       ‹"other_crop"› to ‹"other_crop"›. However, :crop_type is an enum column.
```

So how to test an enum field when its of type enum instead of int in Rails?

Comment: Side note: are you sure you REALLY want to use an enum type here? Its only actually a good choice if the number of options are finate and unchanging. To add new options or remove existing ones you'll have to actually drop the type and define it again (and deal with all the rows that actually use that type). I don't really know the domain you're dealing with but I think having a separate join table with the crop type definitions is going to be a much better solution.

Comment: https://medium.com/swlh/postgresql-3-ways-to-replace-enum-305861e089bc

Comment: Thank you so much @max for this comment. I actually think ill change it to string :D :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [backed_by_column_of_type](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/v5.3.0/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_record/define_enum_for_matcher.rb#L79-L114) when asserting an enum that is backed by enums rather than integers:

```
it {
  should define_enum_for(:crop_type)
    .with_values({ fruit: 'fruit', vegetable: 'vegetable', other_crop: 'other_crop' })
    .backed_by_column_of_type(:enum)
}
```

Comment: The column is not a string. `CREATE TYPE crop_type` actually creates a distinct type. `.backed_by_column_of_type(:crop_type)` might work.